# Probability for the following data.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

Many states have number plates that conform to the following format 
         **letter letter letter number number number** 
the numbers are random ranging from 100 to 999.

1. What is the probability that the next two plates seen(at random) will have numbers of 500 to higher?
2. What is the probability that the sum of the next two plates seen(at random) will have a total of 100 or higher?

Comment: Hello @bug, welcome to MSE. Please explain in the question (not in the comments) what you have tried yourself. Questions in the style "here is the problem, solve it for me" are poorly received here.

Comment: And you have a typo with #2.